# Reset API connection issue

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I am attempting to establish a connection between the Campaigner API and Python by referring to the documentation available [here](https://media.campaigner.com/apidocs/edapi/?_gl=1*ovnuvv*_ga*MzAxMzIwODk5LjE2NzcxMDM2MjU.*_ga_BGYQF4VFQ8*MTY3NzUyNjAxNi42LjEuMTY3NzUyNjAyMy41My4wLjA.#CampaignClicks), but I am encountering the following error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='edapi.campaigner.com', port=443):
> Max retries exceeded with url:
> /v1/Campaigns/1/Clicks?PageSize=2&PageNumber=1 (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate
> chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

This is my code:

```py
import requests

api_key = "12345"
campaign_id = 1

url = f"https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Campaigns/{campaign_id}/Clicks"
params = {
    "PageSize": 2,
    "PageNumber": 1
}
headers = {
    "ApiKey": api_key
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```